# install pip or other extensions fail by cmd

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip

I just get started to using python
and I need to import some extensions

But here is my problem:

When I install some extensions(including pip or yfinance etc...)

cmd will collecting and downloading

then its just stop for no reason

please help me I have no clue ><

My OS is windows7 x64 and I using vscode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzF7x.jpg)

Comment: What is the error msg that you are reciveing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what your problem is or how to solve it. Maybe if you run the console as administrator? Alternatively I would suggest that you use virtual environments for individual projects. In the IDE's you can specify them as interpreters. A tutorial for the virtual environments can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chou Chloe. This is a place for developers to share code and solutions for code. This question is about using a program. You will probably find a better reception at https://superuser.com/